# Rotationally invariant random variable implies uniformly distributed?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $X = (X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n})$ be a random vector such that $\|X\|_{2} = 1$ almost surely and $UX$ is equal in distribution to $X$ for all orthogonal matrices $U$ (so $X$ is rotationally invariant). Must $X$ then be the uniform distribution on the sphere of radius 1? If so, why?

In particular, I am interested in the case when $X_{i} = Y_{i}/\|Y\|_{2}$ where $Y = (Y_{1}, \ldots, Y_{n})$ and $Y_{i} \sim N(0, 1)$.

Comment: If you truncate a two dimensional normal distribution to the unit circle and then rotate around the origin it will remain a 2D normal distribution (truncated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your random variable has a continuous density $\rho$ (like your particular case), then it is quite easy to show what you want. Suppose that for  $r_1,\,r_2\in \mathbb S^n$, $r_1\ne r_2$, and $\rho(r_1)> \rho (r_2)$. Therefore, there exists a radius $\epsilon$ such that on $$D_1=\{r\in \mathbb S^n:\,|r-r_1|<\epsilon\},\\D_2=\{r\in \mathbb S^n:\,|r-r_2|<\epsilon\}$$ you still have

$$\forall r\in D_1 \forall s\in D_2\quad \rho(r)>\rho(s).$$ Therefore, $P(D_1)>P(D_2)$. Yet $D_2$ can be obtained from $D_1$ by a rotation, which implies that $P(D_1)=P(D_2)$. Contradiction, hence such $r_i$ do not exist.

A similar method can be applied to any other probability measure on the unit sphere.